# Read out the link address in EXCEL using AutoIT v.3

Tags: hyperlink, excel-2010, autoit

How can I get the underlying linkaddress of an excel cell using AutoIt v.3 ?
Or, how can I follow this link? Is not an external link, the link opens only another existing sheet in the same workbook.

Comment: Did you try : _Excel_RangeRead